# Linkedin API v2: Receive vanityname on signup linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm doing the sign up integration with LinkedIn for a personal application and i have a big trouble.

We need the `vanityName` in order to make people visible via linkedin.

How we can redirect them to profiles without using vanityName? I tried with `ID` unsuccessfully.

I use this endpoint with `r_liteprofile` scope:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,vanityName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))
```

and it returns me:

```
    {
        "firstName": {
            "localized": {
                "es_ES": "XXX"
            },
            "preferredLocale": {
                "country": "ES",
                "language": "es"
            }
        },
        "lastName": {
            "localized": {
                "es_ES": "XXX"
            },
            "preferredLocale": {
                "country": "ES",
                "language": "es"
            }
        },
        "profilePicture": {
            "displayImage": "XXX",
            "displayImage~": {
                "elements": [...]
            }
        },
        "id": "AX-Wv6r0Ku"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `me` endpoint of the [Profile API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api#retrieve-current-members-profile) in order to Retrieve Current Member's Profile. As example:

```
   https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?oauth2_access_token=<user_access_token>
```

With the result:

```
{
   "firstName":{
      "localized":{
         "en_US":"Bob"
      },
      "preferredLocale":{
         "country":"US",
         "language":"en"
      }
   },
   "localizedFirstName": "Bob",
   "headline":{
      "localized":{
         "en_US":"API Enthusiast at LinkedIn"
      },
      "preferredLocale":{
         "country":"US",
         "language":"en"
      }
   },
   "localizedHeadline": "API Enthusiast at LinkedIn",
   "vanityName": "bsmith",
   "id":"yrZCpj2Z12",
   "lastName":{
      "localized":{
         "en_US":"Smith"
      },
      "preferredLocale":{
         "country":"US",
         "language":"en"
      }
   },
   "localizedLastName": "Smith",
   "profilePicture": {
        "displayImage": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4D00AAAAbBCDEFGhiJ"
   }
}
```

If you want to retrieve only the `vanityName` field you can use the [Field Projections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/projections) as follow:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(vanityName)&oauth2_access_token
```

With the result:

```
{
    "vanityName": "bsmith"
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: This only works with `r_basicprofile` and not with `r_liteprofile`. Linkedin removed `r_basicprofile` and now we can not access to vanity name. I will post more information about the calls i made.