# Can I fetch firstname,lastname,email and profile picture of linkedin with only one api request?

Tags: reactjs, api, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

How can I fetch first name,last name,email and profile picture of LinkedIn with only one API request? #linkedin

Comment: Have you already tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59249318/how-to-get-linkedin-person-id-for-v2-api/59251986#59251986 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57249920/linkedin-api-v2-receive-vanityname-on-signup-linkedin/57251012#57251012 ?

Answer (score 1):

No, email needs a different request as of their documentation

`GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me` will get you first and last name and profile picture.

`GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))` will get you email address.

You need to request the user for `r_liteprofile` permission for the first request and `r_emailaddress` for the second during the [Authenticating process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authentication?context=linkedin/consumer/context).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context